# How to make a background like this?

Tags: background

I would like to do a background like the grey and cloud-like background of this t-shirt.

[image]

Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method in Illustrator: Draw few different horizontal shapes. Give to them gradient fill grey-grey-grey, where mid stop is opaque, but start and end stops are partially transparent. No stroke!. Apply slight gaussian blur.

Make copies in different sizes and drag the copies to different places. You can easily duplicate what you have and move the duplicates as a bunch; there's no need to place them one by one. If the original formation is sparse enough, you can easily fill the artboard with duplicates

Put duplicates to different layers => you can easily change their opacity and gradient settings.

An example:

[image]

Only one shape is drawn. It's the black outline on the top. Copies are stretched to different sizes and some of them is flipped.